# How can I see the MobileFirst old container's log in volume (libertyvol/sysvol)?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mobilefirst

I followed the instructions that are described in [Run IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation on IBM Containers](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/bluemix/run-foundation-on-bluemix/). At last part, I enabled volume(ENABLE_VOLUME=Y) for my container. libertyvol and sysvol were created successfully. libertyvol mounted for `/opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/worklight/logs` and sysvol mounted for `/var/log/rsyslog`.

I deleted this container. Then, I created another container from same image. It is also enabled volume.

I don't see any old logs in `/opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/worklight/logs` and `/var/log/rsyslog`.

How can I see old container's log?

Comment: According to bluemix support, some hosts had a problem. But now this is fixed. I can see old container's logs from new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was issue in automount service due to which the mount was not happening. This was seen in few of the hosts. Now all hosts have been re-installed with autofs service and our team has tested **the mount and shared volumes are working fine**. Due to this issue its possible that the earlier data you wrote through the container was not on this shared volume and hence it was not persisted.
if you delete the container and attach the volume to new container you can see your old data.

**I want remember** that the volumes are effectively just shared folders on SL environment and whatever data (files) is written there will be stored on SL storage. How to write the data or archive it is upto the consumer.
If The archiving of logs done from the application inside the container and not the persistent volume, when you will delete the container all data in the containers will be destroyed.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Once the container is destroyed the log locations /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/worklight/logs and /var/log/rsyslog cannot be accessed in a newly created container, as it is associated with that specific container filesystem. However any old logs can be viewed using the logmet service of the IBM Bluemix Console.(Because of persistence in Volumes)

[IBM Bluemix Logmet Service](https://logmet.ng.bluemix.net/)

You can use the Kibana interface to view all the logs which are persistent. Open the Kibana interface by logging in with your right org & space under which the Containers were created. In the table view of the log listing include few fields in the log view (instance, path, groupid, etc) by selecting them from the [ Current / All ] link.

Comment: Thank you krckumar. But  I can't open your link. Where is the Logmat Service Docs?

Comment: Edited the link to Bluemix Logmet Service. Now it works with https. 

Docs: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/doc/container_ml_ov.html

Comment: Thank you for your telling the link. But now I can see destroyed container's log from new one. And bluemix support says this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Edited answer: this appears to be a problem with the Containers service and was brought to the attention of the developers and maintainers.

Comment: My understanding was that data in volumes should not be deleted once the container is deleted.

Comment: Thanks, Idan and Alex. My understanding is same as Alex. Bluemix Docs says 'A storage volume is persistent. If you delete a container, the storage volume is not deleted. The lifecycle of a storage volume is independent from the lifecycle of a container.'. https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_index.html#container_ov

Comment: Thanks. I've reached out for clarifications from the dev team.